# Converting a hsv image to 3 channels

Tags: java, opencv

I have  a mat image in HSV format and i just want three mat images from it first one of H component ,second one in S component and third one of V component.

I search around but could not found any JAVA code for it .thanks in advanced.Sorry I could not provide any code because i could't even know which method or class to use.

Is any method to split a mat image of HSV format into three Mat Images .

Comment: Surprisingly, the function is called "split"

Comment: @Miki please help me with the coding part

Answer (score 3):

For java you could do something like this:

```
Mat myHSVimage; 
List<Mat> channels = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
Core.split(mHSVimage, channels);
Mat H = channels.get(0);
Mat S = channels.get(1);
Mat V = channels.get(2);
```

Please read [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split) before posting such questions.